# Swift Firestore update sub collection only if id exist

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I want to update a user's gamer tag in all the games they have played if they change their tag, currently I have a collection of games. Here is the structure:

```
(collection) games -> 
   (document) randomId -> 
      (collection) players -> 
         (document) playerId
```

How can I update the playerId document without getting a list of every single game out there? IE I only want to update games that the players has been in and not have to query 15,000 games each time a player changes their gamer tag.

Currently how I do this is like this with nested calls, which doesn't seem correct & could get very expensive down the line. So is there a better way to do this?

```
    //-> Get all the games available
    self.db.collection("games")
        .getDocuments()
    { (querySnapshot, err) in
        //-> Loops through all games
        for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
           //-> Check to see if player exist in this game
           self.db.collection("games")
               .document(document.documentId)
               .collection("players")
               .document(playerId).getDocument { (snapshot, error) in
                guard let _snapshot = snapshot else {return}

                //-> If player exist, update gamer tag
                if _snapshot.exists
                {
                    self.db.collection("games")
                    .document(document.documentId)
                    .collection("players")
                    .document(playerId)
                    .setData([
                        "gamerTag": gamerTag,
                    ], merge: true){ err in
                        if let err = err {
                            print("Error updating gamer tag: \(err)")
                        }
                    }
                }
           }
        }
    }
```